# Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation in Angular 6

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, angular6

In Angular6, I have an error  **Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation**

I used angular CLI version: 6.1.4
angular version:6.1.3
Node:10.9.0
NPM: 6.2.0

When I run ng serve in Terminal its compiled but in browser **localhost:4200** try its shown error. 
error display in Below error.

Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWpNL.png)

Comment: can you post your bookComponent code ?

Comment: you have to add bookcomponent in appmodule.
if this does not solve your error, can you please share your appmodule and bookcomponent code?

Comment: shared both files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my case I had a custom module being Declared in the AppModule. This was unnecessary as the app-routing was handling the custom modules. Just remove the declaration and it worked. hope this helps someone